# Get the final price with discount but only if column is not NULL. SQL

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I use these sql tables with these columns:

**customers:**

| id | name | phone | adress | etc.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Test Name | Test Phone | Test Adress | etc data. |

**orders:**

| customerid | orderid | orderdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | OR_1234 | 2022-1-1 |

**orderitems:** (in this table one customer can have multiple rows(items)

| id | orderid | productid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OR_1234 | P1 |

**products:**

| productid | productprice | currency | qty | name | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 10 | USD | 1 | TEST | 0.2 KG |

So in this case if I want to get the FULL price from the order from customer I use this query:

```
SELECT sum( productprice ) as fullprice
FROM customers 
inner join orders on orders.customerid = customers.id 
inner join orderitems on orderitems.orderid = orders.orderid 
inner join products on products.productid = orderitems.productid 
WHERE customers.id = '1234'
```

This query is working perfectly. But what if I want to add to this query a discount from discount table:

**discount:**

| id | name | value | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Discount | 1 | valid |

So I think I will need to create one more column in orders table with name for example: discount_code and if the discount_code column is not empty than subtract the discount value from productprice.

SELECT sum( productprice - discount.value ) as fullprice but how can I make this query? Thank you for help!

BTW I use MariaDB

Have a very nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to subtract only when your new column is not null, you could simply use IF() func inside you SUM()

In very simple example, assuming you added discount_code

```
create table Orders
(
  id int NOT NULL,
  price int NOT NULL,
  discount_code int NULL  
);

create table Discounts 
(
  id int not null,
  value int not null
);


insert into Orders
values
(1, 10, null),
(2, 10, null),
(3, 5, 1),
(4, 25, 1);


insert into Discounts
values
(1, 3);

select sum(if(o.discount_code is not null, o.price - d.value, o.price))
from Orders as o
left join Discounts as d
on o.discount_code = d.id;

-- 10 + 10 + 2 + 22 = 44
```

You can also run the example [here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/7a0e80cccb3c76600272c902975604df/)

Comment: Thank you, so much! And maybe its an another question but is it possible to make in this query to check that coupon is exist in Discounts table? So it would be: if is not null and with this id is exist in Discounts table? Thank you so much again!

Comment: @kviktor1230, Maybe I misunderstood you, but the query already looking for a discount from Discounts table. Assuming that discount_code is a reference key to Discount table (id field). In other words, if discount_code is null, it means that there is no any related row in the Discounts table. I just didn't create these relationships in my answer, for simplicity purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, today I tried your query but looks like its have an issue.  So if there are more than one product (customer ordered more than one product), then It's multiple substracting the discount value from the product price. I just  created a sample code: https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/47eeb940dfb322b42e163f5d5a9350c4/ 
Thank you!

Comment: @kviktor1230, Yes, it works as expected, as the discount.value applies to the whole order, if you want that discount to be applied to some specific item, I'd suggest having discount in products table, not in the order table in your case.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it but if I move the discount to "orderitems" table in my case, and if I dont have on specific product any discount then it will not calculate the price. like: 
https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/71a9afbe6016c70a910b69122e7dbbc3/
the price should be 75 because one product have discount another not.
insert into orderitems
values
(1, 1, 2),
(1, 1, null);
Thank you again!

Comment: @kviktor1230, just substitute the inner join to left join with your discounts table, as discount_code could contain null. In your last link you have inner, so it won't add your orderitem without discount_code which is not expected. So I changed it a bit, now it works. Check : https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/a6a771303c099020b68da8eaa52f9f86/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its working! :)